# Point in Polygon with geoJSON in Python

Tags: python, geometry, gis, geojson

I have a geoJSON database with lots of polygons (census tracts specifically) and I have lots of long,lat points.

I am hoping that there would exist an efficient Python code to identify which census tract a given coordinate is in, however so far my googling hasn't revealed anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found an interesting [article](http://www.mhermans.net/geojson-shapely-geocoding.html) describing how to do exactly what you are looking to do.

TL;DR: Use [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)

You will find this code at the end of the article:

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
# depending on your version, use: from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

# load GeoJSON file containing sectors
with open('sectors.json') as f:
    js = json.load(f)

# construct point based on lon/lat returned by geocoder
point = Point(-122.7924463, 45.4519896)

# check each polygon to see if it contains the point
for feature in js['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print 'Found containing polygon:', feature
```

Comment: Anybody knows if this is WGS84 compliant?

Comment: To get this to work in Shapely 1.4.4 I needed to change the import statement to from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

Comment: Hi, @Zebs. I found your answer but I can get it to work with my data. If you have time, would you take a look in this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173835/point-in-polygon-geojson-using-shapely-python-always-returning-false. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that we need to switch the lat/long to long/lat to make it work, because Shapely performs its operations in x/y plane. Thanks for the article @pceccon

Comment: I think you need need `open` e.g.: `with open('sectors.json', 'r') as f:`

Comment: very useful question and answer!

Comment: @Zebs would you be kind to offer the example on printing the point that did not have a match in the containment?

I tried with an else and I get a weird behavior with giving me all the points without a match;

Comment: How to automate if I have multiple points in the data frame? extract the matched polygon with point name @Zebs

Answer (score 7):

A great option for working with these types of data is [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), a spatial database extender for [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). I personally keep all of my geo data in a PostGIS database, and then reference it in python using `psycopg2`. I know it's not pure python, but it's got unbelievable performance benefits (discussed below) over pure python.

PostGIS has functionality built in to determine if a point or shape is within another shape. The good documentation on the [ST_Within](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Within.html) function expands upon this simple example:

```
SELECT
ST_WITHIN({YOUR_POINT},boundary)
FROM census;
-- returns true or false for each of your tracts
```

The benifit you'll gain from PostGIS that you likely won't achieve elsewhere is indexing, which can improve your speed 1,000x [1], making it better than even the best written C program (unless the C program also creates an index for your data). The database, when properly setup, will cache information about your tracts, and when you ask if a point is within a tract, it won't have to search everything... it can take advantage of it's index.

Getting data into and out of PostGRES is pretty simple. A great tutorial that will walk you through the basics of PostGIS with sample datasets not too different from yours can be found here. It's reasonably long, but if you're new to PostGIS (as I was), you'll be very entertained and excited the entire time:

http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/

[1] Indexing decreased a nearest neighbor search in one of my huge databases (20 m from 53 seconds to 8.2 milliseconds.

Comment: The tutorial link does not work anymore, but it is also hosted (and revised) here: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/

Answer (score 2):

One cannot have really fast geometric code in Python. Instead the usual approach is to use fast C/C++ library with Python wrappers.

For example, you can start with CGAL - a very comprehensive C++ geometric library. It has Python bindings for most of its routines, see the link http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/.